# Prism 5 Quickstart build gets the error "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."

Tags: prism

I downloaded the Prism 5.0 from the link (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42537). I installed it. I'm trying to build/ run the BasicMVVMQuickstart_Desktop. The build gets the error "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."

This seems really odd to me. Why would a build be trying to connect to something? In any case it shouldn't have a problem, I can use NuGet etc...  I'm just trying to build and run this sample project, which I don't think even connects to any DB or service.  Anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: This exact same question has been answered in the following Discussion **Codeplex** thread: [Prism Quickstart gets "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required." error when compiling ](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/546820). If that was not helpful, please provide more information about your environment configurations. Regarding the **MVVM_QuickStart**, it would not need any particular connection despite downloading the **Nuget** package. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I delete .nuget folder and through VS 2013, I enabled 'Enable Nuget package manager' . By doing this, .nuget folder created successfully and I was able to compile the application. Thanks.