# Prism 5 Sample Project - Error ProxyAuthentication required

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have downloaded Prism 5 sample projects from this link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx

Tried the below project and compiled
Quickstarts\Hello World\HelloWorld.Desktop.
I am using VS2015 Professional.
**I got the below error.**

Error       The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.   HelloWorldModule

I have tried the solutions mentioned in the below link.

[Prism 5 Quickstart build gets the error "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913722/prism-5-quickstart-build-gets-the-error-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-4)

Tried the other ways like
1. changing the proxy
2. removing automatically detect settings.

No clue on what's wrong.

Anyone have any idea about this error?

Comment: Suggestion: If you are going to learn Prism, learn it using the latest version (6.2): https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf

Comment: R. Richards. Thank you very much.